# Why are only some of these geoip values being returned?

Tags: php, apache2

I have a web server running Apache2 on Ubuntu 12.04. I have installed `geoip-database`, `libapache2-mod-geoip1.2.5-2`, `libgeoip1 1.4.8+dfsg-2`, and `php5-geoip`.

I put this test PHP code on my server:

```
<?php
echo "country: " . apache_note("GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME") . '<br>';
echo "code: " . apache_note("GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE") . '<br>';
echo "city: " . apache_note("GEOIP_CITY") . '<br>';
echo "region: " . apache_note("GEOIP_REGION") . '<br>';
echo "latitude: " . apache_note("GEOIP_LATITUDE") . '<br>';
echo "longitude: " . apache_note("GEOIP_LONGITUDE") . '<br>';
echo "timezone: " . geoip_time_zone_by_country_and_region($this->countryCode, $this->region);
```

When I access it in my browser, I get this output:

```
country: Japan
code: JP
city:
region:
latitude:
longitude: 
timezone:
```

I'm confused by the fact that only two of the values are coming back. If the GeoIP module were not installed correctly, would it not fail completely without any values at all?

Are there some libraries or something that I am missing?

How do I get my code to return all the values, like latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using the free [GeoLite](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/) IP database. This database only contains country information.

The databases containing more detailed information, such as latitude and longitude, are available from Maxmind on a paid basis.

Comment: Has this always been the case? I was sure that in the past I was able to get latitude and longitude without having to buy anything.

Comment: I don't know if this has *always* been the case, but if not, it's been this way for a very long time (like, 5-10 years). Maxmind isn't a charity, after all.